# How to log in to Liferay programmatically and avoid [JSONAction:92] User ... must be authenticated errors

Tags: liferay, k6

I'm attempting to construct a k6 load test to exercise a WebSocket endpoint running in Liferay 7.1.

We're having issues with our WebSocket connections in production, so I'm trying to emulate the sign in and WebSocket initialization that occurs in the browser and am therefore using Cookie Authentication (as opposed to Basic, OAuth, or other available authentication mechanisms.

Based on inspecting the flow when signing in with a browser, the flow for signing in and initializing the WebSocket connection is:

1. Navigate to the home page

   ```js
   const homeResponse = http.get('http://localhost:8080');
   ```

   - This loads a whole bunch of assets with a bunch of other requests, but eventually loads the sign in page
2. Parse the `p_auth` token from the home page response
3. Sign in using username / password    - This redirects to `/c/` and then to `/` and loads the home page

   ```js
   const loginResponse = http.post(
     'http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_javax.portlet.action=%2Flogin%2Flogin&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Flogin%2Flogin',
     {
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_formDate: getFormDate(),
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_saveLastPath: "false",
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_redirect: "",
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_doActionAfterLogin: "false",
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_login: username,
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_password: password,
       _com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_checkboxNames: "rememberMe",
       p_auth: csrfToken,
     }
   );
   ```
4. Retrieve a JWT

   ```js
   const getJwtResponse = http.get('/api/jsonws/my-app.auth/create-token?p_auth=xt6uBXfx');
   ```

When I perform this workflow by opening a browser window, navigating to the (Liferay) site, signing in, grabbing the `p_auth` value in the browser developer tools, then opening a new browser tab and sending the JWT response from the new tab's developer tools, I successfully get the requested JWT as the response. When run from my k6 load test, however, the JWT request causes a `[JSONAction:92] User 34253 must be authenticated` error message in the Liferay logs and a redirect to `/generic.html` which then endlessly redirects to `/404.html` .

I have confirmed that k6 is properly passing the `JSESSIONID` and other cookies, and am using the same user in both the k6 and browser operation.

For reference, here's the request/response flow in k6:

```
INFO[0001] Request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Accept-Encoding: gzip

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=b8f3e83c-430b-445f-6d1d-3399193332a2 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0001] Response:
HTTP/1.1 200
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:08 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=87B26F65E129477BB369046C4C1D4B81; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 27-Jun-2024 22:45:07 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 27-Jun-2024 22:45:07 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1

[Liferay home page HTML]

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=b8f3e83c-430b-445f-6d1d-3399193332a2 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2                   source=console
INFO[0001] Request:
POST /web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_javax.portlet.action=%2Flogin%2Flogin&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Flogin%2Flogin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Content-Length: 464
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: JSESSIONID=87B26F65E129477BB369046C4C1D4B81; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US
Accept-Encoding: gzip

_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_checkboxNames=rememberMe&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_doActionAfterLogin=false&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_formDate=1687992308202&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_login=user%40liferay.com&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_password=user&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_redirect=&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_saveLastPath=false&p_auth=Gepd4RjL  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=af481d51-b9f1-40ae-6da8-63b39910f536 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0001] Response:
HTTP/1.1 302
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:08 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Location: http://localhost:8080/c
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: COMPANY_ID=20099; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ID=4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=af481d51-b9f1-40ae-6da8-63b39910f536 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0001] Request:
GET /c HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COMPANY_ID=20099; ID=4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d
Referer: http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_p_id=com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_javax.portlet.action=%2Flogin%2Flogin&_com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet_mvcRenderCommandName=%2Flogin%2Flogin
Accept-Encoding: gzip

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=6b2204de-20a2-477b-468c-3ad7c8e3360f scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0001] Response:
HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:08 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 27-Jun-2024 22:45:08 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=6b2204de-20a2-477b-468c-3ad7c8e3360f scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0001] Request:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COMPANY_ID=20099; ID=4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d
Referer: http://localhost:8080/c
Accept-Encoding: gzip

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=dbe421fb-dc11-483a-7a52-6da68020c327 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0001] Response:
HTTP/1.1 200
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:08 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1

[Liferay home page HTML...]

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=dbe421fb-dc11-483a-7a52-6da68020c327 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0002] Login response cookies:                       source=console
INFO[0002] Cookies:                                      source=console
INFO[0002] Cookie jar after login request                source=console
INFO[0002] Cookies:                                      source=console
INFO[0002] COOKIE_SUPPORT: true                          source=console
INFO[0002] GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID: en_US                      source=console
INFO[0002] COMPANY_ID: 20099                             source=console
INFO[0002] ID: 4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d  source=console
INFO[0002] JSESSIONID: 0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B  source=console
INFO[0002] loginResponse status: 200                     source=console
INFO[0003] JSON Web Service URL (before params): http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-current-user  source=console
INFO[0003] JSON Web Service URL (with params): http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-current-user?p_auth=Gepd4RjL  source=console
INFO[0003] Request:
GET /api/jsonws/user/get-current-user?p_auth=Gepd4RjL HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COMPANY_ID=20099; ID=4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d
Accept-Encoding: gzip

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=86c666ed-00b9-4bb0-63c0-f2af0bb2d689 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0003] Response:
HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:09 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Location: http://localhost:8080/generic.html
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 0

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=86c666ed-00b9-4bb0-63c0-f2af0bb2d689 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0003] Request:
GET /generic.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COMPANY_ID=20099; ID=4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d
Referer: http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-current-user?p_auth=Gepd4RjL
Accept-Encoding: gzip

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=0d03f897-64ed-4d85-6891-4d11d59d5540 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0003] Response:
HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:09 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Location: http://localhost:8080/404.html
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1
Content-Length: 0

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=0d03f897-64ed-4d85-6891-4d11d59d5540 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0003] Request:
GET /404.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: k6/0.44.1 (https://k6.io/)
Cookie: JSESSIONID=0E276C213E82EC575F129E05B7B78C4B; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COMPANY_ID=20099; ID=4665343346716a427041424b695059785871624550513d3d
Referer: http://localhost:8080/generic.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=aed0f815-890b-4fe9-710e-31b2f55ce0d5 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2
INFO[0003] Response:
HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 22:45:09 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Liferay-Portal: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.1.3 CE GA4 (Judson / Build 7102 / May 14, 2019)
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Link: <http://localhost:8080/o/api/doc rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/core#apiDocumentation">
Location: http://localhost:8080/404.html
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1
Content-Length: 0

  group="::login" iter=0 request_id=aed0f815-890b-4fe9-710e-31b2f55ce0d5 scenario=websocket source=http-debug vu=2


[more requests/redirects to/from /404.html...]

WARN[0003] Stopped after 11 redirects and returned the redirection; pass { redirects: n } in request params or set global maxRedirects to silence this  url="http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-current-user?p_auth=Gepd4RjL"
```

How do I adjust my k6 workflow to avoid the `User ... must be authenticated` error and successfully call the JSONWS API?

Answer (score 0):

After setting some breakpoints in the `JSONAction` class, the authentication operation was failing because I was providing the (outdated) CSRF token provided in the initial home page request instead of the CSRF token provided in the login response.

Once I started doing that, the JSON WS calls succeeded.

In summary, the workflow needed to be updated to:

1. Navigate to the home page
2. Parse the p_auth token from the home page response
3. Sign in using username / password, including the p_auth token from the home page response
4. Parse the p_auth token from the login response
5. Retrieve a JWT, including the p_auth token from the login response